# LocalDateTime.of returns null in test class

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit4

I have a class with a `formatToSpecificText(inputDate: LocalDateTime)` method that changes the date to text. In this method, I use the `Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), inputDate)` function. My function returns the specified text with a duration, such as "more than three day".

I would like to write unit tests for this class and method. In this case, I would like to use the `@RunWith(Parametrized::class)` annotation. My test class looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized::class)
internal class DateTest(private val case: TestCase) {

    private val resources = mock<Resources>()
    private val dateFormatter = mock<DateFormatter>()
    private lateinit var binder: DateBinder
    private val mockedNow: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.JULY, 21, 12, 0, 0)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        binder = DateBinder(resources, dateFormatter)
        whenever(
            resources.getQuantityString(
                R.plurals.over_day,
                1,
                1
            )
        ).thenReturn(OVER_1_DAY_LABEL)
    }

    @Test
    fun `should return formatted time string`() {
        mockStatic(LocalDateTime::class.java).use { mocked ->
            mocked.`when`<Any> { LocalDateTime.now() }.thenAnswer { mockedNow }
            val result = binder.formatToSpecificText(case.given)
            assertThat(case.expected).isEqualTo(result)
        }
    }

    private companion object {
        const val OVER_1_DAY_LABEL = "over 1 day"

        @JvmStatic
        @Parameters(name = "{index}: Test with input={0}")
        fun testCases(): List<TestCase> = listOf(
            TestCase(
                given = LocalDateTime.of(2021, Month.JULY, 22, 12, 0, 0),
                expected = OVER_1_DAY_LABEL
            )
        )
    }

    internal data class TestCase(
        val given: LocalDateTime,
        val expected: String
    )
}
```

Everything I put in the given field in the testCases method returns null in binder.formatToSpecificText().

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.time.LocalDateTime.until(LocalDateTime.java:1686)
    at java.base/java.time.Duration.between(Duration.java:488)
    at com.example.DateBinder.formatToSpecificText(DateBinder.kt:17)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Durations between LocalDateTimes don't make sense.  Get a Duration between Instants.

Comment: By the way, I cannot think of any case where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do. That class lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC, so it cannot represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.